# Why Firefox auto gzip download file?

Tags: firefox, download, gzip

I am working on a web file share service, the service can decompress the `.gz` file content before transferring to client if user asks for it: Windows has not gzip build-in.

Following is an example: un-gzip and download `long.txt.gz`.

## Capture from Fiddler

### Request

```
GET https://szdc-data-explorer-test.spiral.exchange/v1/fs/file/tmp/long.txt.gz?pipelines=ungzip&file_name=long.txt&otk=da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 HTTP/1.1
Host: szdc-data-explorer-test.spiral.exchange
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://next-test.spiral.exchange/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="long.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 00:44:14 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Origin
Content-Length: 293216
```

Firefox save the file with name `long.txt` as specified in `Content-Disposition` header, but the content is gzip-ed. It sounds like Firefox auto gzip due to request path ends with `.gz`: `/v1/fs/file/tmp/long.txt.gz`

[image: long.txt opened in 7zip]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a known behavior of firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=610679